# Как запретить менеджеру паролей в Chrome влиять на шрифт в инпуте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, password

Менеджер паролей изменяет шрифт, когда наводишь на какой-нибудь айтем. Как можно этого избежать? Сталкивался кто? Два скриншота прилагаю. Первый, когда просто открылся дропдаун и всё хорошо, второй, когда навёл на один предложенных вариантов.

до наведения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после. Смотрите, плейсхолдер кастомный тоже уезжает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно узнать зачем? Такой перфекционизм!

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko какой ещё перфекционизм? Вёрстка едет при ховере на эту гадость. Это не перфекционизм, это конкретный косяк.

Comment: чтобы минимизировать влияние менеджера паролей,  для инпута, я установил `line-height: 1.1em` . По тестам - работает  любой `line-height`, больше 1em

Comment: @Дмытрык спасибо, но не то. Он, зараза, сам шрифт меняет при выборе какого-нибудь значения. То есть именно при наведении на это значение. После выбора шрифт обратно возвращается на тот, который и нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел вот такую штуку: введите пару раз email/password

```css
@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
  to {
    color: red;
    background: transparent;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<form action='/123'> 
  <input type="email"  name="mail" autocomplete>
<input type="password" name="pass" autocomplete>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, но тут не в автокомплите проблема, а именно в чертовом менеджере паролей. Автокомплит я отрубил и всё хорошо. У коллеги пароль для входа сохранён, и он всегда выпадает вне зависимости от того запретил я автокомплит или нет. Но штуку хорошую нарыли, спасибо. Пригодится.

Comment: autocomplete используется просто для того, чтобы сподвигнуть на работу менеджер паролей... введите пару раз почту, чтобы менеджер начал реагировать и увидете

Comment: Дядька, всё получилось! Я всё утро гуглил! Обгуглился! Спасибо огроменное тебе!!!